# Export button in datatable does not take filters into consideration

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables, export, reload

im new here , i write you because i have a problem when i export data from datatable i export the data without filtring : here is my code javascript

```js
$('#returnview').DataTable({
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        bInfo: false,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5'

        ],
        function: showReturnViewData()
       


    });
function showReturnViewData() {
   
    
    var contractType = $("#contractTypes").val();
    var company = $("#company").val();
    var year = $("#selectdate").val();

   
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = ''

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/Operations/showReturnViewData",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { contractType, company, year },
        success: function (data) {
           
            
                var displayReturnView = JSON.parse(data.returnViewData);

            for (var i = 0; i < displayReturnView.length; i++) {
                var tr = "<tr>";
                var sum = 0;
               
                sum += parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Decommissioned) + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].LocalStock) + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Return)
                    + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Replace) + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Missing) + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].UnRepair)
                    + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Used) + parseInt(displayReturnView[i].Repair);

                tr += "<td><a style='cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; color: blue;' target='_blank' href='/DecommissioningTarget?contractType=" + contractType+"&&company=" + company + "&&date=" + displayReturnView[i].DecommissioningdDate + "'>" + displayReturnView[i].DecommissioningdDate + "</a></td>" + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].Decommissioned +
                    "</td>" + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].Return + "</td>" + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].LocalStock + "<td>"
                    + displayReturnView[i].Replace + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].Used + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].Repair + "</td>" + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].UnRepair + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + displayReturnView[i].Missing + "</td>" + "<td>" + sum + "</td>"
                "</td></tr>";

                    tbody.innerHTML += tr;

            }

        }
    });
    var x = document.getElementById("returnview").rows.length;
    document.getElementById("rvEntries").innerHTML = x - 1;
   
}
```

Comment: i understand you are new but you are putting too much code and not much explanation where you are getting the code. perhaps, it will be better if you put code in a sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
                      name of param    
       get string     in the method    variable
            |               |             |
data: JSON.stringify({ contractType: contractType }),
```

or:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ contractType: $("#contractTypes").val() }),
```

multiple args:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ contractType: contractType, company: company, year: year }),
etc...
```